# angular 1.5: factory to component

Tags: angularjs

its possible to change the binding of a component from a factory in angular 1.5.8?

(I want prepare a factory to display msgs when my http-interceptor caught an error 500)

For example.

Thats factory:

```
 angular.module('app')
    .factory('msgFct', ['$log', '$timeout', tuiMsgFct]);

    function tuiMsgFct($log, $timeout) {
      var module  = {};
      var self    = module;

      module.foo = function() {
        var node = document.getElementById('js-foo');

        node.setAttribute('bar', 'Awesome');
      };
      return module;
    }
```

To set thats bindings

```
/// COMPONENT IN DOM
<foo-component id="js-foo" bar=""></foo-component>

 //// COMPONENT TEMPLATE
<span>{{fooComponent.bar}}</span>

 //// COMPONENT CONTROLLER

  angular.module('app').component('fooComponent', {
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: fooComponent,
    controllerAs: 'fooComponent',
    bindings: {
      bar: '<'
    }
  });

  function fooComponent() {
    var self = this;

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a factory to do this and don't use the component binding to reply assign your value ?

Comment: Hi, because the interceptor rest is in a factory.